# In metaphilosophy, what should I call a foundational document?

Tags: untagged

I am planning the structure of a blog to write some
pieces on **metaphilosophy**, but each post will base its
topics on entire paradigms of interpreting various
aspects of the universe, uncommon enough that 95%
of visitors will not immediately understand what I’m
talking about.

Thus, I need to have a collection of separate posts
solely to describe these paradigms that I can link to,
so that I don’t have to keep explaining complex ideas
in the middle of each new post whenever something is
brought up.

It would serve a purpose like an extremely detailed glossary.

What should this collection of foundational writings
be called? At first I thought of using *theses*.

Obviously, given the subject matter, everything is
theoretical, so then I thought of saying:

> *thesis*: a hypothetical proposition,
> especially one put forth without proof.

This might be a good definition from
*thesis*. However, they won’t be nearly so long as
we would normally imagine a thesis to be.

Then I thought about saying:

> *suppositions*: a fact, theory, etc, that is supposed.

Anyone have anything more flavorful?

Comment: Just after posting this, in unrelated research, I stumbled upon the phrase "theoretical framework" in a study, which sounds great. I just wonder if there's anything more concise.

Comment: The noun **postulates** comes to mind.

Comment: If foundational, they are *The Paradigm Core* more than theses.

Comment: I don't get questions like this. It seems to me that if you had read the literature in this domain, you probably would not be asking this question.

Comment: Correct, I have not. I do a lot of thinking and not a lot of reading. Working on fixing that.

Comment: What's wrong with *Paradigms*?

Comment: Finding a title would be more easy and precise if you give us some examples of the intended posts.

Comment: *Assumptions* seems like a good fit.

Comment: I suppose there's no need to make it more complicated than _assumptions_, yeah. After all, I'm going to try to make it as approachable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your second paragraph asks for a name of the collection but elsewhere you seem consistently to be asking about the items in the collection. I therefore assume that you need a word for those items similar to *thesis* or *supposition*.

I suggest that **proposition** may answer your need:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition)
> Proposition: a central concept in the philosophy of language, semantics, logic, and related fields, often characterized as the primary bearer of truth or falsity.

> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/proposition)
> Proposition: a statement that affirms or denies something and is capable of being true or false

Both definitions and many usages (such as in mathematics and logic) reconise that a proposition may be false or true. Your items are concerned with "paradigms of interpreting ..." and therefore sound as if they may be true or false, certainly meriting discussion.

**Proposition** is therefore one of the words applicable to your work.

Comment: Asking about both, because the section of the site would use the plural, and on each of the posts I would reference one of these in the singular.